# Need statistics on usage of Java, Eclipse and TDD

Tags: java, eclipse, tdd, statistics

Does anyone has references to the following numbers?

1) Number of developers using Java as their **main** language.

2) Percentage of Java developers using Eclipse as an IDE.

3) Percentage of Java/All developers using TDD.

Comment: Oracle claimed 9 million statistic for Java developers in 2010, that on **average** use Java 61.6% of their time. Oracle's required 1% for being classed as a Java developer. But this doesn't say how many of these use Java most of their time.

Comment: According to this http://www.zeroturnaround.com/blog/the-2011-turnaround-container-and-tools-pre-report-snapshot/ 64% of Java developers use Eclipse.

Comment: According to this http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/blog/?p=541 50% of developers use TDD. Seems exaggerated to me.